# How to simulate slow copying of a file in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, file, batch-file

I have an issue in a Windows Production environment which is caused by files being copied into a directory very slowly.
I would like to find a way to copy files slowly in a Test environment.
I could write a program to do that myself, but I was wondering if anybody had a better idea e.g. an option in an existing Windows command perhaps?

Comment: Simulation != reproduction. You might be sending yourself on a fluke hunt for something that has nothing to do with the actual production issue :)

Comment: Apologies. I have reworded the question: I hope it makes more sense now.
Anyway @Gosseyn below understood what I was looking for and his reply is spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robocopy has a /IPG switch. It might help you.
I tried copying a folder with /IPG:500 and it's slower than normal copy.